# Formula to capture 5 letters on contact name

Tags: formula, formula-field

I was wondering if it is possible to capture 5 letters off of a contacts full name based on its sequence? for example:

eg. Surname J**ol**i**e**-Pitt, First Name A**n** **g**ie

Result: OLENG

Non-alphabetic characters (eg. Hyphens (as in Lee-Archer) apostrophes (as in O'Mara) or blank spaces (as in Eu Jin) should be ignored when counting the position of each character

Answer (score 0):

Formulas don't provide any convenient way to strip a set of characters, but you can call SUBSTITUTE as many times as needed.  I'd recommend putting this into a hidden field so you don't have to copy and paste it when finding your letters.

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LastName, " ", ""), "'", ""), ",", ""), "-", "")
```

---

```
RIGHT(LEFT(LastName_Stripped__c, 3), 2) & RIGHT(LEFT(LastName_Stripped__c, 5), 1)
& RIGHT(LEFT(FirstName_Stripped__c, 3), 2)
```